# Adjust overpic size to accommodate annotations

Tags: margins, bounding-box, overpic

How to make a bounding box around `overpic` that includes the added contents (such as `\put`, etc.)?

For instance below `\fbox` does not take into account the `\put` commands nor the grid labels.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\fbox{
  \begin{overpic}[grid,scale=0.5,unit=1mm]{tiger}
    \put(45,20){\textcolor{red}{blah blah right}}
    \put(20,30){\rotatebox{90}{\textcolor{red}{blah blah top}}}
  \end{overpic}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By design and as explained in the documentation, the environment has the same dimensions as the included image, so you will need to tell `\fbox` how much bigger you want it to be, if you do it this way. (Or change the way the environment works, of course.) I don't understand why you'd do this with `overpic` as it doesn't seem suitable for your needs. With something like Ti*k*Z, you could do it straightforwardly, but you want to tighten your screws with a pencil sharpener, so life is obviously going to be tricky.

Comment: @cfr "life is obviously going to be tricky": sorry it was not obvious to me. I'll go with tikz.

Comment: I was just going by what the documentation for `overpic` says. It is only about 3 pages long with plenty of pictures, so a pretty quick read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says, the dimensions of the `overpic` environment are the dimensions of the included image. By design, it does not do what you want. Hence it would be better to use something more amenable to your desiderata or, alternatively, to change your desiderata. Since people are usually more open to the former than the latter, I suggest a solution in this vein.

This is relatively straightforward in Ti*k*Z, though not entirely so as the use of dimensions rather than a relative scale makes this a bit more complex. Still, it is very doable in Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newlength\mylength
\newlength\mywidth
\newlength\myheight
\begin{document}
\centering
\fbox{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \pgfmathsetlength{\mylength}{.9\linewidth}
    \node [inner sep=0pt, fill=gray] (img) {\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{tiger}};
    \draw [orange] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
    \pgfmathsetlength\mywidth{.9\linewidth/1mm}
    \settoheight\mylength{\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{tiger}}
    \pgfmathsetlength\myheight{\mylength/1mm}
    \begin{scope}[shift=(img.south west)]
      \foreach \i in {0,10,...,\mywidth} \node [anchor=north] at (\i mm,-2.5pt) {\i};
      \foreach \i in {0,10,...,\myheight} \node [anchor=east] at (-2.5pt,\i mm) {\i};
      \draw [red] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
      \node [red, font=\large\sffamily\bfseries] at (110mm,60mm) {Roar!};
      \node [magenta, font=\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries] at (75mm,115mm) {Tiger, tiger in the night \dots};
    \end{scope}
    \draw [blue] (current bounding box.south east) rectangle (current bounding box.north west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

The `\draw` lines are just there to indicate the bounding box at various points during the picture's construction. The thin outer line in black is, of course, the `\fbox` rule.

[image: Tiger, tiger ...]